# Javascript - Count in numbers the length of an array of strings

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

It's a bit strange to explain, but I have an array of strings, I get the length of it, for example 5. I can easily print out the number '5', right.

```
const myArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

myArray.length = 5;
```

BUT what to do when I want to display the numbers '1 2 3 4 5' on my page, let's say each in their individual p tag? The contents of my array are not numbers. There's just 5 of them. I would need to *count that out* on the page if that makes sense.

```
myArray.??? = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 1 2 3 4 5
```

If anyone has any ideas, let me know.

Comment: Honestly speaking not properly clear. Could you plz post your expected output?

Comment: Are you simply looking to return the range of values `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` when supplied `5`?

Comment: Loop over it extract index and start counting at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @ScottSauyet yes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is often called a `range` function.  There are many ways to do this in Javascript.  Here's one I sometimes use:

```js
const range = (lo, hi) => [...Array(hi - lo + 1)].map((_, i) => lo + i)

const vals = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']

console.log(range(1, vals.length))
```

This does not check that your inputs are integers or that `hi >= lo`.  Those are easy enough to add, depending upon your needs.

#### Explanation

We start by creating the number of elements we want by subtracting the `lo` value from the `hi` one and adding 1.  (Adding one is because we include *both* ends of the range.  `range(5, 7)` should have three elements, not two: `5`, `6`, and `7`.)  We pass this value to the `Array` constructor, which creates a sparse array with length `n`.

The trouble is that when Javascript tries to iterate this new array, it doesn't bother visiting the missing elements, so we turn it into a similar, but not identical array by treating it as an iterable and turning that back into an array: `[...Array(5)]`.  The difference is simple.  The first array had a length of 5, but no properties such as `0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, or `4`.  The new one has such properties, each with the value `undefined`.  (`3 in Array(5) //=> false`, but `3 in [...Array(5)] //=> true`.)

Now we map over these values, using the second parameter to `map`, which tracks the index of the elements in our array.  Because we're ignoring the first parameter, we give it the throw-away name of `_`.  Adding that index to the low value gives us our range element.

So `range(3, 8) //=> [3 + 0, 3 + 1, 3 + 2, 3 + 3, 3 + 4, 3 + 5]` which is `[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]`.

#### Variations

If you're always going to use `1` for the start of your range, you could write a version without it, but the code will be only a little simpler and the function will be less flexible.  But if you wanted it, that would be

```
const range = (hi) => [...Array(hi)].map((_i) => i + 1)
```

But more flexibility could be created by currying the original function:

```
const range = (lo) => (hi) => [...Array(hi - lo + 1)].map((_, i) => lo + i)
const rangeFrom1 = range(1)
```

which you could use like this:

```
console.log(rangeFrom1(vals.length))
```

This gives you both the generic range and one that always starts at one.

Answer (score 2):

**Though I'm not sure that**, this is what you want or not? but Let's do it with simple `forEach()` if I understood your question properly,

```js
const myArray = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'];

myArray.forEach((element, index)=> {
  var para = document.createElement("P"); // Create a <p> element
  var t = document.createTextNode(`${index+1}`); // Create a text node
  para.appendChild(t); // Append the text to <p>
  document.body.appendChild(para); // Append <p> to <body> 

})
```

Comment: A great answer, it works. Any idea how to do it in React, JSX?
It gives me an error for using 'document'

Answer (score 2):

You could use JSX with ES6 to do something like this:

```
render() {
  return <div>
    {
      myArray.map((element, index)) =>
        <p>Element #{index} is {element}</p>
    }
  </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got your point correctly this is what you are looking for (using ES6):

```js
var dt = ["a", "b","c", "d"];

for (let idx in dt)
{
  let new_node = document.createElement("p");
  new_node.innerHTML=idx;
  document.getElementById("container").appendChild(new_node);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```